# How to convert views to bitmap and save as Image?

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I am trying to convert views to bitmap and save as image! I found some method to do that but it doesn't work in Android 10 or higher version!

Here is my XML code:-

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:background="@color/teal_200"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnSaveID"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/kohli" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSaveID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:paddingLeft="50dp"
        android:paddingRight="50dp"
        android:text="@string/save"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/layout1" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and Here is my Java Code:-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    LinearLayout layout;
    OutputStream outputStream;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        layout = findViewById(R.id.layout1);


        findViewById(R.id.btnSaveID).setOnClickListener(v -> {

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
                String requiredPermission = Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;
                int checkVal = checkCallingOrSelfPermission(requiredPermission);

                if (checkVal == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    saveImage2(layout);

                } else {
                    checkPermission(layout);
                }
            } else {
                saveImage2(layout);

            }
        });

    }

    private void saveImage2(LinearLayout layout1) {
        layout1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        layout1.buildDrawingCache();
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(layout1.getWidth(), layout1.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        if (bitmap != null) {
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
            layout1.draw(canvas);

            Drawable bgDrawable = layout1.getBackground();

            if (bgDrawable != null) {
                bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
            } else {
                canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
            }

            layout1.draw(canvas);

            String folderName = "/VIRAT kOLI/";
            File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + folderName);
            if (!dir.exists()) {
                dir.mkdirs();
            }
            File file = new File(dir, System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");
            try {
                outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outputStream);
            try {
                outputStream.flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                outputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            String xy = file.getAbsolutePath();
            MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(MainActivity.this, new String[]{xy}, new String[]{"image/*"},
                    new MediaScannerConnection.MediaScannerConnectionClient() {
                        public void onMediaScannerConnected() {
                        }

                        public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                        }
                    });

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Saved to" + file.getAbsolutePath(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Unable to download now! This feature coming soon.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private void checkPermission(LinearLayout layout) {
        PermissionListener permissionListener = new PermissionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPermissionGranted() {
                saveImage2(layout);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPermissionDenied(List<String> deniedPermissions) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission required to download", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };

        TedPermission.with(MainActivity.this)
                .setPermissionListener(permissionListener)
                .setPermissions(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                .check();
    }

}
```

Here is the Manifests file code:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.noobprogroammer.sampleproject">

    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.SAMPLEPROJECT">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.noobprogroammer.sampleproject.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I have added the custom file path as follows:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

Can anyone check my code? As mentioned earlier, it's not working in Android 10 and higher, failing with `NullPointerException`

Comment: Post the stacktrace of the exception

Answer (score 1):

Use this method. It will save bitmap to Pictures folder (MediaStore API)

Also learn more about [Scoped storage](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage)

```
    public static Uri savePng(Context context, Bitmap bitmap, @NonNull String name) throws IOException {
        Uri uri;
        OutputStream fileOutputStream;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
            contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, name + ".png");
            contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/png");
            contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
            uri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues);
            fileOutputStream = resolver.openOutputStream(Objects.requireNonNull(uri));
        } else {
            String imagePath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString();
            File image = new File(imagePath, name + ".png");
            fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(image);
            uri = getUriFromPath(context, imagePath);
        }
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fileOutputStream);
        fileOutputStream.close();
        return uri;
    }


    private static Uri getUriFromPath(Context context, String imagePath) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
            return FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "com.noobprogroammer.sampleproject.fileProvider", new File(imagePath));
        return Uri.fromFile(new File(imagePath));
    }


    protected void openImage(Uri uri) {
        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
            startActivity(intent);
        }catch (Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error opening image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I've try this code... It works on android 10 and upper version. But it's not working on android Oreo.. why? Kindly give me solution.