# Saved images don't appear in gallery

Tags: android, image, file, storage, android-external-storage

I'm using getExternalFilesDir("Pictures") to save pictures in the storage, the get saved in Android/my.package.name/Pictures
but they don't appear in Gallery.

I was using Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() with mediaScanner and it was working just fine but now it's deprecated.

Comment: "they don't appear in Gallery" -- on Android 10+, the `MediaStore` will not index files in app-specific external storage directories. Gallery-style apps frequently use the `MediaStore` to find the images to display.

Comment: so I should just keep using Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() ?

Comment: AFAIK, that will only work for a few more months. Long term, you might consider using `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` to let the user choose where on the user's device (or in the user's cloud storage) the user wants you to put the user's images. Alternatively, you could use `MediaStore` more directly and store your image in standard image locations on external storage (e.g., in a subdirectory off of `Pictures/`). See [this series of blog posts](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/19/scoped-storage-stories-saf-basics.html) for more on both techniques.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information, I really appreciate it, I will try to do that

Comment: You saved image to app private place that is not visible to the user as media. Learn more about Scoped storage and find my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65978729/how-to-convert-views-to-bitmap-and-save-as-image/65978917#65978917

Comment: @adnandann thanks a lot man, you just saved my day, it worked for me perfectly fine

Comment: If you save to external storage (accessible to gallery apps) you could also use MediaScanner